# How are you supposed to do client-side data fetching on route transition with getServerSideProps?

Tags: next.js

Next.js 9.3 introduced `getServerSideProps`. In the [`getInitialProps` documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps) it now says:

> If you're using Next.js 9.3 or newer, we recommend that you use `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps` instead of `getInitialProps`.

The thing is: `getInitialProps` doesn't just provide props on the server side. It also runs on the client and provides props when a route transitions. After an initial server render, if the route changed, `getInitialProps` runs on the client. So, how do the new methods introduced in 9.3 account for this pretty basic use case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### `getServerSideProps`

> `getServerSideProps` only runs on **server-side** and never runs on the browser. If a page uses `getServerSideProps` , then:
>
> When you request this page directly, `getServerSideProps` runs at the request time, and this page will be pre-rendered with the returned props.
>
> When you request this page on client-side page transitions through next/link (documentation) or next/router (documentation), Next.js sends an API request to the server, which runs `getServerSideProps`. It’ll return JSON that contains the result of running getServerSideProps, and the JSON will be used to render the page.
>
> All this work will be handled automatically by Next.js, so you don’t need to do anything extra as long as you have `getServerSideProps` defined.

For [more info](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering).

### `getStaticProps`

> Only runs at build time
>
> When a page with getStaticProps is pre-rendered at build time, in addition to the page HTML file, Next.js generates a JSON file holding the result of running getStaticProps.
>
> This JSON file will be used in client-side routing through next/link (documentation) or next/router (documentation). When you navigate to a page that’s pre-rendered using getStaticProps, Next.js fetches this JSON file (pre-computed at build time) and uses it as the props for the page component. This means that client-side page transitions will not call getStaticProps as only the exported JSON is used.

For [more info](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation)

Comment: Yikes. Not sure how I missed all this in the docs. Thanks a lot.